# Disable automatic redirection after signout in FBA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, forms-authentication, sharepoint-administration

In my application when the user clicks on signout menu I'm redirecting to default sign out page (_layouts/SignOut.aspx) but this page is not asking for the confirmation to close the browser to complete the sign out which is the default behavior. Instead of that after signout response is automatically getting redirected to home page.

Can anyone suggest how to change this configuration for closing the browser after signout instead of redirection to home page and force closing the browser after signout.

Anonymous authentication is also enabled on this web application. Is this the reason for the automatic redirection to home page after signout?

Answer (score 0):

To enable signout, configure the SharePoint STS with a ProviderSignOutUri property. This will sign the user out of SharePoint then redirect them to the provider's signout URL.

```
$sts = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer
$sts.ProviderSignOutUri = "http://"
$sts.Update()
```

Comment: It is already getting redirected to the signout page (_layouts/SignOut.aspx) but it is not asking for the window to close and it is automatically getting redirected to home page.. Is there any way to prevent this behavior

Comment: It's a known issue. As a workaround, you could try to redirect them to login page.

Comment: If we redirect to login page it will not logout the users. Due to security reasons we need to force users to close the browser after signout.. Please let me know if there is any work around for this issue..